# Check if modules offer required functions without executing them

Tags: python, function, module

I am importing a variable number of modules that all need to offer the same functions (`func1`, `func2`, `func3(n)`).

I know all the modules names and need to verify that they all - at least offer the function, without executing them (e.g. **not** something like `try  something = mod1.func1 except NotWorking: print("nope")`) or parsing the whole module for the presence of "`def func1:`".

How could I verify that these modules offer said functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are objects, and methods are just attributes of those objects. You can use the normal `getattr` and `hasattr` functions:

```
hasattr(mod1, "func1")
```

But this sounds like a strange way to do things. It would probably be better to use a class with a proper inheritance mechanism, so that the superclass defines the interface by declaring abstract methods (which can do nothing but raise `NotImplementedError`) and the subclasses implement that interface.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! I've never used inheritance/superclasses - I guess I have to look into that.. sounds reasonable!